# Are there performance reasons to prefer size over length or count in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, collections

In [Airbnb's Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#size-over-count) one suggestion reads:

> Prefer `size` over either `length` or `count` for performance reasons.

What would these performance reasons be?

Comment: For `Enumerator`, `size` attempts to calculate the size whereas `count` actually counts the elements by traversing the entire collection.

Comment: You should read http://web.archive.org/web/20100210204319/http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size

Comment: `count` is more suitable when used with a block or argument, something like `collection.count { |x| x.price > 10 }`.

Comment: @Kimmo,  yes, `count` is more suitable when used with a block or argument, but then `size` and `length` take neither an argument nor a block. :-)

Comment: @stefan Yes this. I was pleasantly surprised trying stuff like `p (1..200).to_a.combination(9).size` , which returns 1175445251780800 almost instantly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems a bit wrong, for most commonly used cases (`Array`, `Hash`, `String`), `size` and `length` are either aliases or are implemented in the same way (you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816739/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-length-methods) or check the implementation of each method) and will run in `O(1)`.

`count` however:

- For `Hash` is not redefined and will fallback to [`Enumerable#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count), which means its complexity will be `O(n)` as all key-values will be traversed.
- For `Array` it is redefined ([`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-count)) and at the very least it will check the number of arguments given which is something that neither [`Array#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-size) nor [`Array#length`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-length) have to do.
- for `String` it's used to count substrings.

All in all, I would say that

> Prefer `size` or `length` over `count` for performance reasons.

would be more accurate.

Comment: One answer at the link you give provided a link to [this article](https://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/), which I thought was very helpful.

Comment: Please also remember that AirBNB is a rails application at heart so their style guide is most likely geared towards this as well. `count` from an AR perspective is a query execution where as size defers to `Array#size` thus using size has far less overhead than `Select COUNT(*) FROM xxx`

Comment: @engineersmnky I haven't mentioned AR as the guide is named "Ruby Style Guide"while Rubocop's guides distinguish Ruby vs Rails. I also do not think that the answer is very straightforward in this case, as when getting counts for AR relations, pagination and whether the records have already been loaded comes into play which makes it difficult to write a generalized statement about what is better.

Comment: My point was not whether or not you mentioned it but rather that the guide is written by Airbnb and the first line states "This is Airbnb's Ruby Style Guide." which implies that it might have some leanings. Which looking at the examples it certainly does. Also Airbnb makes not such distinction but rather included a rather brief Rails section.